# Make a form on another thread "belong" to parent form?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I've created a new form which I am running on a separate thread to the parent form. Here is the code in the parent form that displays it.

```
_newFormThread = new Thread(() =>
{           
     if (_newForm == null)
    _newForm = new NewForm();

    if (!_newForm.Visible)
    {
       _newForm.ShowDialog();
    }
});
_newFormThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);  // This is needed as there's a webbrowser control on it.
_newFormThread.Start();
```

However, even though it's in a different thread, I'd like this new form to still "belong" if you get me to the parent form, in other words, appear on top of the parent form when it's active.

I've tried this in the child form's `Shown` event...

```
this.TopMost = true;
this.Focus();
this.TopMost = true;
```

... however now it's always on top, even if a window from a different application is the focus. I only want it on top if the parent form (or, I'll settle for the parent application) is in focus, as if it was just a regular child form.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why create a form on another thread at all? What do you expect to gain from this? If you want to run a CPU-bound job, run only that on a separate thread. The easiest way to do this is to use `Task.Run` and `async/await.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Because of complexities & processing within the main application and the particular requirement (e.g. updating the afforementioned `WebBrowser` control, invoking Javascript on it) of this form, I've found the most efficient way has been to place the entire form in its own thread. Would `Task.Run` help if part of what I want to run on the separate thread was updating the form itself?

Comment: And that's exactly why you shouldn't be trying to create a form on a separate thread. There's a reason nobody tried to use this technique in the 25 years since Windows 95 introduced true multitasking. It's the *least* efficient way to work with forms

Comment: As for a WebBrowser control, none was mentioned in the question. If you do use a WebBrowser control - don't. That ancient control uses IE11. It's far, far, far better to use either Chromium through CefSharp, the (old by now) [WebView](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/) control that uses the (old) Edge engine or the current [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) control that uses the current Edge Chromium

Comment: Thanks, I will check them out - however WebView would require me to increase the version of .NET for the entire project (currently 4.5.1) - this is supposed to be a relatively minor update to a very large and complex application and that is something I would rather avoid if possible. I had not heard of CefSharp, I'll check it out.

Comment: 4.5.1 is 8 years old and most likely *not found on any of your clients*. .NET 4.x runtimes are binary replacements - any newer runtime installed by eg Windows Update or another application will replace the runtime. I suspect you already have problems with TLS1.2 and using NuGet packages too, as developers publish for .NET Standard 2.0 at least, which is really usable in 4.7 and later.

Comment: As for TLS1.2, unless you use a hack, you won't be able to connect to any web service that requires TLS1.2, as most major services do now.